# Java - How do I refer to the previous and next element during an iteration?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

When I have a *for loop*, I use the `i` to refer to the elements of my array, objects, etc.

Like:
Current item: `myArray[i]`
Next item: `myArray[i+1]`
Previous item: `myArray[i-1]`

But at the moment, I'm using a **foreach** loop ( `for (Object elem : col) {` ).
How do I refer to the previous item?
(I need to do a search an 'array', which I'm doing with `for (Object object : getComponents())`.

But when it returns true (so it finds what I look for), it should perform the code on the *previous* and the *next* item.

**Clarification:** I have `java.awt.Component` elements!

Comment: (I can think about a workaround like using a temporary / disposable integers, to 'mark' these items. Like tempInt1, tempInt2. I would use an additional marker, and if it returns true, I would use these integers like: tempInt2 = mark-1 and tempInt2 = mark+1. And then just manipulate the marked ones.)

Comment: But I guess there must be a cleaner way to do this. :D

Comment: why not go for normal for loop?

Comment: @Bhushan - The lack of normal education... I guess? :)

Comment: The foreach-loop is practical, but quite limited.  I often have to use the old for-loop.

Comment: Found a similar question, but the solution uses the same foreach loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037139/loop-through-jpanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JButton prev, next, curr;
Component[] arr = getComponents();

for(int i=1;i<arr.length-1;i++) {
    if (yourcondition == true) {
        curr = (JButton) arr[i];
        prev = (JButton) arr[i-1];
        next = (JButton) arr[i+1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If the data-structure is a List, then you can use a [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) directly. The ListIterator is special because it contains both the methods `next()` and [previous()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous%28%29)

```
List list = ...;
ListIterator iter = list.listIterator(); //--only objects of type List has this
while(iter.hasNext()){
    next = iter.next();
    if (iter.hasPrevious()) //--note the usage of hasPrevious() method
       prev = iter.previous(); //--note the usage of previous() method
}
```

Comment: Of course, it should be noted that `previous()` moves the iterator _backwards_, meaning a pair call to 'next()` and 'previous()` will cause a net effect of having the iterator stay in place.

Comment: Same thing, problem with the awt like objects. Should I convert them into a list, or the values into a list, change the values and then back to *objects?

Comment: @X-Zero, right, that's why I explicitly mentioned that in the code-comments, and the purpose was only to show the usage :)

Comment: @Suraj - You don't mention that `previous()` moves the iterator **at all** (although it might be inferrable because of `next()`).  All the `hasPrevious()` does is prevent exceptions from being thrown - you need another call to `next()` in there for the loop to actually advance...

Comment: As noted in the other comments, beware that this code will not advance the iterator, and as such will not work as the OP expected. You need another next() at the end to make it work correctly, which ends up being not a particularly clean solution.

Answer (score 5):

The `foreach` loop won't let you do that.  My suggestion is to go back to using the good old fashioned `Iterator`.  For example

```
final Iterator itr=getComponents().iterator();
Object previous=itr.next();
Object current=itr.next();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Object next=itr.next();
    //Do something with previous, current, and next.
    previous=current;
    current=next;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it in 15minutes and report back. Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't the two calls to itr.next() before the while loop cause the while loop to start at the third element in the collection?

Comment: @DaveHowes There are 3 variables : previous, current and next.

Comment: @Jack: I have java.awt.components... and the Iterator gives me an error because of that. :-/

Comment: @DaveHowes When the loop starts, previous is the first element, current is the second element, and next becomes the third element.  I probably should have put some guards just in case the list didn't have 3 elements but I was worried that might clutter up the code and make it more difficult to understand.

Comment: @JackEdmonds - yes - I re-read and I saw that it worked. It just feels a little counter-intuitive that the first itr.next() in the while loop doesn't retrieve the first element from the collection, and that the element that has just been read from the iterator is assigned to the "next" variable. Having said that, I can see that the code would work.

Answer (score 1):

I did this to access the previous and next elements in a list while using enhanced for loop.

Here's a quick snippet:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<>();
    myInts.add(1);
    myInts.add(2);
    myInts.add(3);
    myInts.add(4);
    myInts.add(5);

    Integer next = null;
    Integer previous = null;

    for (Integer current: myInts) {
        try {
                previous = myInts.get(myInts.indexOf(current)-1);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){
               // ignored
            }
        try {
                next = myInts.get(myInts.indexOf(current)+1);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){
                next = null;
            }
        System.out.println("previous = " + previous);
        System.out.println("current = " + current);
        System.out.println("next = " + next);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
previous = null
current = 1
next = 2
previous = 1
current = 2
next = 3
previous = 2
current = 3
next = 4
previous = 3
current = 4
next = 5
previous = 4
current = 5
next = null
```

Yeah! I know, the code's ugly. But, it get's the job done.

Answer (score 0):

#### Array indexing

If you have an *array-like* data-structure (e.g. an actual array or something like an `ArrayList`), then referencing `i`, `i-1`, `i+1` will give good performance so there isn't much more to it.  (Although having to turn a For-Each Loop into an index counting For Loop isn't very fun and is one of the few caveats.)

The answer offered by Sergey does something like this.

#### The versatile `ListIterator`

If you can get your hands on an `ListIterator` (which is actually quite a big assumption), the answer offered by Suraj could suffice.  But do note both `next()` and `previous()` **moves the iterator position**.  So if you did something like the following for each loop iteration: `prev = previous(); current = next(); next = next(); previous()`, you'll end up performing roughly 4 iteration operations per loop.  This isn't much of a problem if **iteration is cheap**, and luckily this is often the case for data-structures that offers a `ListIterator`.

#### Generic solution

The generic solution for any [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) (or `Iterator`) should make no random lookups (as is possible with an array) or make assumptions regarding performance of `next()`, which should be called at most N times where N is the number of available elements.

Here's one such implementations:

```
final Iterator<E> it = iterable.iterator();

for (E next = (it.hasNext() ? it.next() : null), current = null; next != null;) {
    E previous = current;
    current = next;
    next = it.hasNext() ? it.next() : null;

    // Do something using 'current', 'previous' and 'next'.
    // NB: 'previous' and/or 'next' are null when 'current' is
    // the first and/or last element respectively
}
```

Mind, this implementation has caveats of its own:

- It'll break if `Iterable` contains `null` elements.
- Neither `current` or `next` are *effectively-final*, so cannot be used directly in them fangled Java 8 lambdas.