# Java Set default disabled textfield text to black instead of grey

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextfield

### Problem

I have a problem where by I have to disable 10 textfield but the default text become grey.
I know we can use

> `textfield1.setDisabledTextColor(Color c)`

. But I will have to do this for all 10 textfield, which I find it irreverent.

Is there another option for me to change the UI manager so by default its black?
btw, I am using netbean GUI builder.

### Code

> txtField1.setEnabled(false);
> txtField1.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037139/loop-through-jpanel) previous SO question as an example, you could do something like so:

```
for (Component c : pane.getComponents()) {
    if (c instanceof JTextField) { 
       ((JTextField)c).setEnabled(false); 
       ((JTextField)c).setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

I think that this should give you more control over your components.

Comment: this only works if I create textfield by hand? What about drag and drop ?

Comment: @searchfunction: `pane` in this case is the parent component which will hold all the text fields, so the code does not really care how you add the components.

Comment: oh ok..i got it to work...thanks. Just some error in ur code. replace the line to  ((JTextField)c).setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);